# Metadata in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: managed-metadata, open-with-explorer

Is it possible to show/change SharePoint Metadata in Windows 7 Explorer?

My company likes to create document libraries with hierarchies in Metadata (Tags, Year, etc.), which results in a complete mess up in the Explorer. I need to do bulk copies of files, based on that Metadata.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot see/change metadata in Windows Explorer.

What you can do is in your document library settings, utilize the column default values. This allows you to set specific metadata on a folder so that when items are placed it it, they get tagged with that information.

This will then allow you to sort and filter better in SharePoint, but not in Explorer. This might be advantageous enough for them to stop using Explorer.

Comment: I 100% agree. Explorer is just for uploading or moving files around if need be. SharePoint is where the rest is managed.